# Ant Macro use element's content as the value of an attribute

Tags: ant, macros, attributes, replace, element

I want to use the content of the element named "soql" as an attribute in a replace filter. What I wanted to achieve is to replace a value in a file with the contents of an element. In this case I am inclined to not use an attribute as the value should be enclosed within CDATA block

```
 <macrodef name="exportdata">
            <attribute name="file"/>
            <attribute name="object"/>
            <element name="soql"/>
            <sequential>
                <echo message="Exporting @{object}"/>
                <mkdir dir="data/exports"/>

                <copy file="data/config/template-process-conf.xml" tofile="data/config/process-conf.xml" overwrite="true" failonerror="true"/>

                            <replace file="data/config/process-conf.xml">
                            <replacefilter token="_endpoint_" value="${sf.serverurl}"/>

                    <replacefilter token="_username_" value="${sf.username}"/>
                    <replacefilter token="_password_" value="${encryptedpassword}"/>
                            <replacefilter token="_object_" value="@{object}"/>
                            <replacefilter token="_soql_" value="@{soql}"/>
                            <replacefilter token="_file_" value="data/exports/@{file}.csv"/>
                    <replacefilter token="_keyfile_" value="data/config/key.txt"/>
                        </replace>

                <java classname="com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner" classpath="lib/DataLoader.jar" failonerror="true">
                    <sysproperty key="salesforce.config.dir" value="data/config"/>
                    <arg line="process.name=export@{object}"/>
                </java>
            </sequential>
        </macrodef>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a reasonably up-to-date version of Ant (>1.7) you may be able to use a [string](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#string) resource to do this.  Here's a simple example:

```
<macrodef name="element2string">
  <element name="elem"/>
  <sequential>
      <string id="elem.as.string"><elem/></string>
      <echo message="${toString:elem.as.string}"/>
  </sequential>
</macrodef>

<element2string>
    <elem><![CDATA[There be <dragons>]]></elem>
</element2string>
```

Result:

```
[echo] There be <dragons>
```